# Responsive menu toggle on image click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried alot of things. I'm a novice when it comes to programming, but it's fun to learn. In this instance I'm trying to show my `<ul>` when the `.menyIkon` is clicked. This for better usability on mobile devices.

Hope you can give some advice or point me in the right direction. I am at the moment stuck..

The code as follows:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsiv</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hide_show_009.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="hide_show_009.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

           <header>

                <a href="#" class="menyIkon"></a>
                <a href="#" class="menyLogo"></a>

                <div class="meny">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Produkter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tjenester</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Om</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </header>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 1024px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.meny
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

.meny ul
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.meny li
{
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.meny ul li a
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menyIkon
{
    display: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(knapp_mobil_liten_50px.png) no-repeat center;
}

.menyLogo
{
    display: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width: 284px;
    background: url(header_001_mobil_50px.png)no-repeat center;
}





@media only screen and (max-width : 900px)
{
    .wrapper
    {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 640px;
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
    }

    .meny
    {
        background-color: #34a5f5;
    }

    .meny ul li
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .showMeny
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .menyIkon
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }

    .menyLogo
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menyIkon").click(function(){
        $(".meny").toggleClass(".showMeny");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the . from your toggleClass function:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/v6e5n

```
$(".menyIkon").click(function(){
    $(".meny").toggleClass("showMeny");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue lies in `toggleClass(".showMeny")` You do not need the `.` in there. Change it to `toggleClass("showMeny")` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Good to know! Make sure to mark @isherwood's answer as the accepted one. We both said the same thing, but he beat me to it (and put more effort in with the jsfiddle)

Comment: Sure! Didnt know about that @Dryden Long :)